# UI testing with AVPlayer

Tags: cocoa, avplayer, xcode-ui-testing

I'm looking for a way to test my application that use an *AVPlayer*.

How can I load a video file? I tried to record the manipulation but recording stop when calling *NSOpenPanel.runModal()*.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you have a sample project where I could give it a try?

Comment: Do you just need a video object to be loaded or are you trying to test something within the video player itself?

Comment: I just need a video object to be loaded.